# How to Train/fine-tune + Deploy LLAMA 7b on AWS trainium and Inferentia with/without Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model

I was just curious, is it possible to train/fine-tune + deploy the LLAMA-2 7b-chat model in AWS Trainium, Inferentia from AWS sagemaker/EC2 or any other easier way?

Also, is Inferentia scaleable to 1M users for example?

Or Am I asking too much :),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one [resource](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/jumpstart-foundation-models/aws-trainium-inferentia-finetuning-deployment/llama-2-trainium-inferentia-finetuning-deployment.ipynb) from sagemaker itself which was useful for me.